# How can i loop through the entire JSON and get all the empids?

Tags: jquery, json

I have a JSON as folows

```
{
  "name": "Employee Fields",
  "id": "Employee",
  "rows": [
    {
      "data": [
        {
          "emp": "111",
          "label": "Name",
          "disabled": false
        },
        {
          "emp": "112",
          "label": "Name",
          "disabled": false
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "data": [
        {
          "emp": "113",
          "label": "Name",
          "disabled": false
        },
        {
          "emp": "114",
          "label": "Name",
          "disabled": false
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "data": [
        {
          "emp": "115",
          "label": "Name",
          "disabled": false
        },
        {
          "emp": "116",
          "label": "Name",
          "disabled": false
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

[image]

How can i loop throuh all the empIds??

https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/70859/

Comment: Going to that link will *freeze your browser*. I suggest you fix that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  var fields = 
  {
    "name": "Employee Fields",
    "id": "Employee",
    "rows": [
      {
        "data": [
          {
            "emp": "111",
            "label": "Name",
            "disabled": false
          },
          {
            "emp": "112",
            "label": "Name",
            "disabled": false
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "data": [
          {
            "emp": "113",
            "label": "Name",
            "disabled": false
          },
          {
            "emp": "114",
            "label": "Name",
            "disabled": false
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "data": [
          {
            "emp": "115",
            "label": "Name",
            "disabled": false
          },
          {
            "emp": "116",
            "label": "Name",
            "disabled": false
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  };


  $.each(fields.rows, function(index, row) {
    $.each(row.data, function(index, emp) {
      console.log("Label: ", emp.label);
      console.log("Disabled: ", emp.disabled);
      console.log("ID: ", emp.emp);
      console.log("----");
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
    var foo = {
      "name": "Employee Fields",
      "id": "Employee",
      "rows": [
        {
          "data": [
            {
              "emp": "111",
              "label": "Name",
              "disabled": false
            },
            {
              "emp": "112",
              "label": "Name",
              "disabled": false
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "data": [
            {
              "emp": "113",
              "label": "Name",
              "disabled": false
            },
            {
              "emp": "114",
              "label": "Name",
              "disabled": false
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "data": [
            {
              "emp": "115",
              "label": "Name",
              "disabled": false
            },
            {
              "emp": "116",
              "label": "Name",
              "disabled": false
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
    
    foo.rows.forEach(row => {
     row.data.forEach(e => {
      console.log(e.emp)
     })
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `map()` and `concat()`

```js
var data ={"name":"Employee Fields","id":"Employee","rows":[{"data":[{"emp":"111","label":"Name","disabled":false},{"emp":"112","label":"Name","disabled":false}]},{"data":[{"emp":"113","label":"Name","disabled":false},{"emp":"114","label":"Name","disabled":false}]},{"data":[{"emp":"115","label":"Name","disabled":false},{"emp":"116","label":"Name","disabled":false}]}]}
let result =[].concat.apply([],data.rows.map(({data})=>data.map(({emp})=>emp)))

console.log(result)
```

And also use `reduce()`, `map()` and `concat()`.

```js
var data ={"name":"Employee Fields","id":"Employee","rows":[{"data":[{"emp":"111","label":"Name","disabled":false},{"emp":"112","label":"Name","disabled":false}]},{"data":[{"emp":"113","label":"Name","disabled":false},{"emp":"114","label":"Name","disabled":false}]},{"data":[{"emp":"115","label":"Name","disabled":false},{"emp":"116","label":"Name","disabled":false}]}]}
let result = data.rows.reduce((r,{data})=>r.concat(data.map(({emp})=>emp)),[]);

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the desired result by using the ES6 `map` and `reduce` methods.

You will store this `JSON` object to a variable.

`const response = <JSON VARIABLE ABOVE>`

`const rows = { response }; //destructure the rows from the response variable`

To retrieve an array of the IDs, you can do the following:

```
const ids = rows.map((row) => {
    return row.data.map((d) => {
    return d.emp;
  })
}).reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b), []);
```